# Mostrar varias personas que se asignan a una palabra en específico - Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

He creado un modelo `persona` con un campo llamado `Eventos` y aparte otro modelo llamado `eventos` concatenado con una clave foránea, donde cada vez que agrego un evento tengo la posibilidad de agregar a la persona que tengo registrada. ¿Cómo haría yo para buscar dichos **Eventos** y que me salgan todas las **personas** que yo agregué a ese evento?

[image: Datos de la Persona.]

Aquí debería de mostrar a las personas que asigné a ese evento en específico.

[image: Datos de la Persona.]

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que hiciste fue crear una relación de muchos a muchos de la siguiente forma:

```
Persona (models.Model):
       evento = models.ManyToManyField(Evento)

Evento (models.Model):
       pass
```

entonces deberías ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
evento.persona_set.all()
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, y mantener una lógica de lo que haces, es mejor, definir modelo con respecto a esos campos de la siguiente manera:

models.py

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    # campos de la clase persona

class Evento(models.Model):
    personas = models.ManyToManyField(Persona, related_name='eventos')
```

Esto lo que quiere decir, es que una persona puede tener muchos eventos, y un evento puede tener muchas personas. Podrías perfectamente añadir el campo `eventos` a persona con un `ManyToManyField` a la tabla Evento (en este caso deberías quitar la relación que te mostré, que seria el campo `personas` en la tabla Evento), y funcionaria exactamente igual, la diferencia es lógica, es decir, es más fácil decir, que tienes un evento al que van muchas personas, a decir que hay una persona la cual asiste a muchos eventos, de esta forma (como mi ejemplo), tienes una estructura más organizada en tus modelos.

La forma luego de recuperar las personas de acuerdo a un evento es la siguiente.

```
# Obtienes tu evento
evento = Evento.objects.get(id=1)
evento.personas.all()
```

Si quieres obtener los eventos de una persona, seria así:

```
# Obtienes tu persona
persona = Persona.objects.get(id=1)
persona.eventos.all()  # este hace referencia al related_name que pusimos en models.py
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda, comenta.